# How to take the value out of a directory that is inside a list?

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, polymer

I'm using JSON, Java and polymer in my code.

When my button is pressed a function will be called and the java backend will send a list of "teachers". It prints it out on my website as the following:

Code :

```html
 handleAjaxResponse(result) {
    this.$.response_text.textContent = JSON.stringify(result.detail.response.docenten);
```

Result:

```html
[{"docentnaam":"Alex"},{"docentnaam":"Jos"},{"docentnaam":"Dick"},{"docentnaam":"Annemarije"},{"docentnaam":"Martijn"},{"docentnaam":"John"},{"docentnaam":"Bart"},{"docentnaam":"Bart"},{"docentnaam":"Peter"},{"docentnaam":"Dietske"},{"docentnaam":"Peter"}]
```

It seems to be a directory inside a list, i don't need all those information. The only thing i need is the values inside the directory.

My code in Java:

```html
 public void handle(Conversation conversation) {
  JsonObject jsonIn = (JsonObject) conversation.getRequestBodyAsJSON();
  String name = jsonIn.getString("user");
  JsonObjectBuilder objBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
  objBuilder.add("message", "The server says: Hi " + name + "!");
  JsonArrayBuilder docentenlijst = Json.createArrayBuilder();
  informatieSysteem.getDocenten().forEach(docent -> docentenlijst.add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("docentnaam", docent.getVoornaam()).build()));
  objBuilder.add("docenten", docentenlijst.build());
  conversation.sendJSONMessage(objBuilder.build().toString());
 }
```

I tried alot to figure out how to get the values out of it only but nothing helped. I hope someone can help me out. Thank you very much.

Polymer/html:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-radio-button/paper-radio-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="my-presentie">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }

      #lijst {
      position: fixed;
      left: 550px;
      top: 300px;
      }
      #studentenlijst {
      position: fixed;
      left: 850px;
      top: 280px;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="lijst">
      <paper-radio-group selected="klas">
      <paper-radio-button name="v1b">V1B-ICT</paper-radio-button><br>
      <paper-radio-button name="v1c">V1C-ICT</paper-radio-button><br>
      <paper-radio-button name="v1d">V1D-ICT</paper-radio-button><br>
      <paper-radio-button name="v1e">V1E-ICT</paper-radio-button>
    </paper-radio-group>
    <paper-button on-click="clickHandler">Volgende</paper-button><br/>

 </div>

  <div id="studentenlijst">
    <paper-input label="Uw naam:" value="{{name}}"></paper-input>
    <p>Studenten: <span id="response_text"></span></p>
  </div>

   <iron-ajax id="studentenlijst_call" method="POST" url="/example" handle-as="json" on-response="handleAjaxResponse"></iron-ajax>

  </template>

<script>
 /**
 * @customElement
 * @polymer
 */
 class WebappApp extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-presentie'; }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      name: {
        type: String,
        value: ''
      }
    };
  }
  clickHandler() {
    this.$.studentenlijst_call.contentType="application/json";
    this.$.studentenlijst_call.body = { "user": this.name };
    this.$.studentenlijst_call.generateRequest();
  }

  handleAjaxResponse(result) {
    this.$.response_text.textContent = JSON.stringify(result.detail.response.docenten);
  }
}
window.customElements.define(WebappApp.is, WebappApp);
</script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: `It seems to be a directory inside a list, i don't need all those information. The only thing i need is the values inside the directory.` what do you mean by this, you want only the values like `Alex ,Jos,Dick ..etc `  ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want

Comment: It's an array of objects. You could just loop through the array and get every object's "docentnaam". (lachen joh)

Comment: Are you going to show the JSON on a webpage? In that case you could just do `for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { console.log(result[i].docentnaam) }`

Comment: show ur html as well, may be we can help

Comment: Ok i'll add it now

Comment: Ok it's i added it. Thanks Jeff (lachen xD)

Comment: instead of directly assigning the values to `this.$.response_text.textContent = JSON.stringify(result.detail.response.docenten);` you can iterate over it and get the values as suggested by @JeffHuijsmans, and then assign that string to the `this.$.response_text.textContent `

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use array.map method;

```
 handleAjaxResponse(result) {
    var r = result.detail.response.docenten;
    this.$.response_text.textContent = r.map(o=> {return o.docentnaam;})
  }
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
<script>
var docents = [{"docentnaam":"Alex"},{"docentnaam":"Jos"},{"docentnaam":"Dick"},{"docentnaam":"Annemarije"},{"docentnaam":"Martijn"},{"docentnaam":"John"},{"docentnaam":"Bart"},{"docentnaam":"Bart"},{"docentnaam":"Peter"},{"docentnaam":"Dietske"},{"docentnaam":"Peter"}]



document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= docents.map(o=> {return o.docentnaam;} );

</script>
```